# Fixing "reference/assignment to free variable" warning during compilation if variable is dynamically bounded

Tags: variables, byte-compilation, warning

For:

```
(defun my-ag/font-lock-extend-region ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char font-lock-beg)
    (forward-line 2)
    (setq font-lock-beg (point))))
```

I've got:

```
Warning: reference to free variable 'font-lock-beg'
Warning: assignment to free variable 'font-lock-beg'
```

Documentation says:

```
font-lock-extend-region-functions is a variable defined in ‘font-lock.el’.

Each function is called with no argument; it is expected to adjust the
dynamically bound variables ‘font-lock-beg’ and ‘font-lock-end’; and return
non-nil if it did make such an adjustment.
```

Usual solution `(defvar ...)` make this variables globally visible and may hide bugs.

How should I mask "reference/assignment to free variable" warning during compilation if variable is dynamically bounded?

Comment: These variables _are_ `defvar`ed in `font-lock.el`, so it is safe for you to do so too.

Comment: "`(defvar ...)`[...] may hide bugs" - what kind of bugs are you thinking of?

Comment: As @sds said, these are *global variables*, declared as such in `font-lock.el`. If you load `font-lock.el[c]` before byte-compiling then you will see no such warning.  Put `(require 'font-lock)` in your file that you're byte-compiling, and the warnings should go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using lexical binding, if the variable is dynamic, then it *must* be `defvar`'d (to ensure that lexical binding cannot treat it otherwise). AFAIK it would be a bug to *not* use `defvar`.

For a variable `foo` defined by some other library, you need only use:

```
(defvar foo)
```

to mark it as special/dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to lexical vs dynamic binding. Now I see that *dynamically bounded* variables should be `defvar`.